# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, установка переменной

Tags: python

Я делаю запрос к вк на получение названия приложения

> ident = await msg.api.apps.get(app_id=f"{user['online_app']}")

Далее вот что я получаю от вк:

```
    {
"response": {
"count": 1,
"items": [{
"id": 3140623,
"title": "iPhone",
"icon_278": "https://pp.userap...1cd/jYgtCgisvic.jpg",
"icon_139": "https://pp.userap...1cc/Utm5omKNcjw.jpg",
"icon_150": "https://pp.userap...1cb/ubXprNEp4YQ.jpg",
"icon_75": "https://pp.userap...1c9/bWuCDuNnQ6s.jpg",
"banner_560": "https://vk.com/images/dquestion_u.png",
"banner_1120": "https://vk.com/images/dquestion_v.png",
"type": "standalone",
"author_url": "https://vk.com/club7278106",
"author_group": 7278106,
"members_count": 73589945,
"leaderboard_type": 0,
"is_in_catalog": 0,
"installed": true
}]
}
}
```

Далее я пытаюсь установить в переменную, название приложения:

> onlineka = ident['items']['title']

Но выходит ошибка

> ```
> onlineka = ident['items']['title']
> ```
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Вот весь код:

```
if msg.is_multichat:
        all_users = await msg.api.messages.getChatUsers(chat_id=msg.chat_id, fields='name,online,last_seen')

        users = ""
        onlineka = ""
        emojis = ""

        for user in all_users:
            random.seed(user['id'])

            if self.show_offline:
                users += f" [id{user['id']}|{user['first_name']} {user['last_name']}] " \
                         f"{' - онлайн' if user['online'] else ''}\n"

            elif user['online']:
                if user['last_seen']['platform'] == 2:
                    onlineka = "(iPhone)"
                elif user['last_seen']['platform'] == 3:
                    onlineka = "(Ipad)"
                elif user['last_seen']['platform'] == 4:
                    onlineka = "(Android)"
                elif user['last_seen']['platform'] == 5:
                    onlineka = "(Windows Phone)"
                elif user['last_seen']['platform'] == 6:
                    onlineka = "(Windows 10)"
                elif user['last_seen']['platform'] == 7:
                    onlineka = "(Браузер)"
                else:
                    ident = await msg.api.apps.get(app_id=f"{user['online_app']}")
                    onlineka = ident['items']['title']

                if user['id'] in self.admins:
                    emojis = " "
                else:
                    emojis = " "      

                if not text:
                    users += f"{emojis}{user['first_name']} {user['last_name']} " + onlineka + "\n"
                else:
                    users += f"{emojis}[id{user['id']}|{user['first_name']} {user['last_name']}] " + onlineka + "\n"

        if self.show_offline:
            await msg.answer(f' Состав беседы \n' + users)

        else:
            await msg.answer(f' Сейчас в беседе \n' + users)

    else:
        await msg.answer("Эту команду можно использовать только в беседе.")
```

Comment: `ident['items'][0]['title']` очевидно

Comment: Спасибо большое